# Are the generated AWS API Gateway URL's safe to hard-code into applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-api-gateway

Are the generated API Gateway URL's safe to hard-code into applications?

I looked into creating a custom domain, and it seems like a decent amount of work in order to get a custom domain running through API Gateway. I really didn't want to have to dive into certificates, SSL and all that in order to get a consistent endpoint.

If I was to say, code a distributed application to point to the URL that is generated when I deploy the API, could I safely add end points and deploy other versions of the API without breaking the apps that are pointed to that URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of security, they are safe to hard-code as long as you require authorization. However API Gateway is deployed in different stages that you specify. You can create multiple stages like dev, test, prod. You can redeploy these stages with new changes. If you were to make a prod2 stage then the url would change. The base url format is: https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.[region].amazonaws.com/[stage].

Comment: This is a good answer, keep in mind that even if you hard-coded the stage name into the app, if someone discovered it they could guess other stage names so make sure that all your stages are secured with some form of auth.

Comment: How is authentication relevant to this question? There is nothing that indicates that this API should be private. Granted, someone might find a dev stage but 1). it is irrelevant to the question at hand and 2). if the API should be public, why would I add authentication (unless to specifically "hide" an alternative stage)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the API id will remain then same once it has been given. 
As long as you do not delete the API you can rely on the base uri to remain the same.